# export subversion/SVN TAG from repository (with phing)

Tags: svn, phing

I'm looking to do exactly and only that.
Export a tag we created in SVN to a certain directory.

Does anyone know if there is a SVN command to do that?

If possible, is it possible to do from a phing task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about phing, but if it can execute a command line exe then this is your ticket:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html

**Update**
Looks like it can:
http://phing.info/docs/guide/stable/chapters/appendixes/AppendixC-OptionalTasks.html#SvnExportTask

Comment: thank but there is no info about exporting a tag (only rev's) on the link you provided. On phing: it has an export task, but no parameter to pass a tag to export

Comment: Tags are typically just another directory next to trunk, but it depends on your particular svn setup.

\root\project\trunk\   OR
\root\project\tags\v1\   OR
\root\project\tags\v2\

Comment: I tagged a version in SVN, and I try to search for it with find or updated locate in my linux system and cannot find the tag anywhere. I also don't seem to have a tags directory in svn

Comment: When you created the tag it should have asked you where to put it.  You may try exploring what is in your svn repository ( svn list ) vs what is local, I believe that making a tag only happens on the server, not in your local copy.

Comment: I found it, you are right, SVN just created directories inside its system. thanks!